# randomly replace elements in a matrix

Tags: r, random

I would like to randomly replace elements in a `matrix` with some specified value, here `-99`.  I tried the first method below and it did not work.  Then I tried a different approach, also below, and it did work.

Why does the first method not work?  What am I doing incorrectly?  Thank you for any advice.

I suspect the second method is better because, apart from working, it allows me to specify the percentage of the elements I want replaced.  The first method does not since it can randomly draw the same `i,j` pairs repeatedly.

Here is the first method, the one that does not work:

```
# This does not work

set.seed(1234)

ncols    <-  10
nrows    <-   5
NA_value <- -99

my.fake.data <- round(rnorm(ncols*nrows, 20, 5))

my.fake.grid <- matrix(my.fake.data, nrow=nrows, ncol=ncols, byrow=TRUE)
my.fake.grid

random.i <- sample(ncols, round(0.40*nrows*ncols), replace = TRUE)
random.j <- sample(nrows, round(0.40*nrows*ncols), replace = TRUE)

my.fake.grid[random.j, random.i] <- NA_value
my.fake.grid
```

Here is the second method, the one that does work:

```
# This works

set.seed(1234)

ncols    <-  10
nrows    <-   5
NA_value <- -99

my.fake.data <- round(rnorm(ncols*nrows, 20, 5))

my.fake.grid <- matrix(my.fake.data, nrow=nrows, ncol=ncols, byrow=TRUE)
my.fake.grid

my.fake.data2 <- c(my.fake.grid)

random.x <- sample(length(my.fake.data2), round(0.40*length(my.fake.data2)), replace = FALSE)

my.fake.data2[random.x] <- NA_value

my.fake.grid2 <- matrix(my.fake.data2, nrow=nrows, ncol=ncols, byrow=FALSE)
my.fake.grid2
```

Comment: In the first case, you used `replace=TRUE` so elements got repeated. If you check `my.fake.grid[random.j, random.i]` it would not be of the same size (bigger ) as your `my.fake.grid`.  also,  `round(0.40*nrows*ncols)[1]20` is twice that of `ncols#[1] 10`

Comment: Try `my.fake.grid[cbind(sample(nrows, round(0.40*nrows)), sample(ncols, round(0.40*ncols)))] <- NA_value`

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thank you.  I will play around with that some.  Right now it only replaces 4 elements, rather than ~ 40% of elements.

Comment: Try `temp <- expand.grid(seq_len(nrows), seq_len(ncols));
my.fake.grid[as.matrix(temp[sample(nrow(temp), round(0.40*nrow(temp))),])] <- NA_value`

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you, David.  Consider posting that as an answer.  I will upvote it and probably select it after 24 hours or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could try

```
library(data.table) # For faster cross/join, alterantively could use expand.grid
temp <- as.matrix(CJ(seq_len(nrows), seq_len(ncols))) # Create all possible row/column index combinations
indx <- temp[sample(nrow(temp), round(0.4 * nrow(temp))), ] # Sample 40% of them
my.fake.grid[indx] <- NA_value # Replace with -99
sum(my.fake.grid == -99)/(ncols * nrows) # Validating percentage
##[1] 0.4
```